# Videos recorded with ReplayKit have some embedded metadata with defaults like "[app store app name]" "[developer]"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm setting up ReplayKit in my IOS App. When previewing the share functionality the emails and text messages include the string:

[app store app name] by [developer]
http://www.apple.com

I can't find anything about this in the documentation. Does anyone who has already shipped a ReplayKit feature know if real values will be substituted in an app store build or do I need to add this information myself either programmatically or in a plist file somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they insert the right content when you app is live, and the app is running with WiFi connection.

Comment: Thanks that is indeed the case. I answered my own question, but Jon Clements deleted my answer, sorry for anyone who was left hanging for 6 months.